# Mailchimp Replace Content in Mail

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am using Mailchimp API 3.0:

```
$api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';     
$list_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';


/* --------------- */

 $apiKey = $api_key;
 $campaignId = "XXXXXXXXX";
 $dataCenter = substr($apiKey, strpos($apiKey, '-') + 1);

$url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/aXXXX/actions/test';
$jsonEmail = '{"test_emails":["XXXX@XXX.com"],"send_type":"html"}';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'apikey:'.$apiKey);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonEmail);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
echo $httpCode;
echo '----';
print_r($result);
exit();
```

It is okay but there are two fields, FNAME and LNAME, in the email. 
I want to replace that with subscribers' FNAME and LNAME values, but it's showing 'Test FNAME' and 'Test LNAME'. How can I replace that? 
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way to view subscribers' merge tag values in a test email, even if the test recipient is also subscribed to the list(s) for the campaign.

However, the '<< Test FNAME >>' and '<< Test LNAME >>' values in your email are placeholders for the merge tag values, so sending your campaign should result in actual first and last names showing up.

The only way to test actual merge tag values is to use MailChimp's website, although that may not be ideal if you want to use the API. [It is recommended to do so](https://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/previews-and-tests/my-test-emails-show-test-first-name-or-test-last-name), however:

> We strongly recommend you preview and test your campaigns before you send to your contacts.

You can follow [these steps](https://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/previews-and-tests/my-test-emails-show-test-first-name-or-test-last-name#Preview-Contact-Information) to enable live merge tag info when previewing the campaign on the website:

> 1. Click the Preview and Test drop-down menu and choose Enter preview mode.
> 2. Toggle the slider to the green checkmark to Enable live merge tag info.
> 3. Use the left and right arrows to move through your list's contacts.